# Read id xml with java in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to add some data to a xml file like:

```
<people>
   <person name="Jo">
      <number>0</number>
      ...
   </person>
   <person name="Steve">
      <number>5</number>
      ...
   </person>
</people>
```

where name is an id value. I use this expression because I need to know if some child have the same name I want to add so I only need to write:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
Element person = doc.getElementById("myname");
```

so I don't need to do loops with all nodechild. My problem is that for this I need to define a schema but Java returns me an error in the forth line of the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
docFactory.setValidating(true);
docFactory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");                      
docFactory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", "my schema in a string");                       
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

the error is:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage

and I have imported:

```
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
 import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;


 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

why do I have this error? Of course I can do this using name as a child and reading all in a NodeList and then using a loop but I think this way has a better performance.

PS: I insert the schema as a string. I don't know if I will have an error because the error is in the previous line but in case I need to have the schema in a file, where do I save the file? In raw folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to put name as a value and not as an attribute and do loops. It was the only option I archive.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes you can always do with `DOM`, `SAX` and `Pull Parser`, but please do look at these below mentioned to Parse and Manipulate the XML data.

**-** `JAXP` and `JAXB`

**-** `Castor`